# Error while using support-v4 and and appcompat-v7

Tags: android

These are my dependencies in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile files('libs/jdom-2.0.6.jar')
```

}

If I rebuild project I get this errors.

```
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.EditText'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Title'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
Error:(121, 22) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(125, 22) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
Error:(123, 22) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(124, 22) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(122, 22) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(119, 22) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(120, 22) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
Error:(128, 22) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
Error:(121, 22) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(125, 22) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
Error:(123, 22) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(124, 22) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(122, 22) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(119, 22) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(120, 22) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
Error:(128, 22) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Borderless'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Small'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ButtonBar'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.CompoundButton.CheckBox'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.CompoundButton.RadioButton'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.DropDownItem.Spinner'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ImageButton'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.PopupMenu'.
Error:(215, 22) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListPopupWindow'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView.DropDown'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.PopupMenu'.
Error:(215, 22) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.RatingBar'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.SeekBar'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.TextView.SpinnerItem'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Toolbar.Button.Navigation'.
Error:(121, 22) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(125, 22) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
Error:(123, 22) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(124, 22) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(122, 22) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(119, 22) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(120, 22) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
```

What is exactly the problem? I want to use the appcompat-v7 because I implement the Navigation Drawer.

What can I do to solve the problem.

**EDIT:**

I edited my gradle like:

```
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
```

But I get some other errors:

```
\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.1.1\res\values-v23\values-v23.xml
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
```

Here is my complete gradle File:

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "de.example.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    repositories{
        mavenCentral()
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile files('libs/jdom-2.0.6.jar')
}
```

Comment: That is not problem with two dependencies...We can add both a time..you should decrease you compileSDK version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use the both library: v4 and v7 both

Simply switch to the only one latest library which is better i.e.:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

**v7 includes the v4 support library so there is no need to have it in there again**

try to add this also

```
 compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
```

Your build.gradle file may have problem like compleSdkVersion or buildToolsVersion.

Therefore, when you are using support and design v23 you have to compile against SDK 23.

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.1.1'
```

and also try to check 23.0.1 instead 23.1.1 if you may not have your sdk update, trying to utilize.

Finally after posting you build.gradle i found you change
`targetSdkVersion 23`, also clean, rebuild project, try to restart if possible. 
Thanks

Comment: Oh well I didn't know that. Thank you for this information!

Comment: I erased the support-v4 but I get the same errors

Comment: please try my updated answer if helps, otherwise show you build.gradle, also update sdk

Comment: so I have now: compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.1.1"

Comment: and just: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'

Comment: Is that right? Because I got the error

Comment: whatever i am using the same, please post you build.gradle completely and then i may find, solution,

Comment: added the whole build.grade file.

Comment: try to use: targetSdkVersion 23, also clean, rebuild project, try to restart if possible. Thanks

Comment: my pleasure if my answer was helpful to you,

Comment: I would be very thankful if you can vote up my question as well! :)